# Enhanced Desktop Zoom won't magnify desktop icons or screen edges

Tags: 16.04, zooming

I'm visually impaired and just installed Ubuntu 16.04.  I'm trying to use compizconfig's Enhanced Desktop Zoom.  It almost works, but it won't magnify anything when the mouse gets to the edges/corners of the screen.  In the 'main' part of the screen it works fine.  I can zoom on different windows and things, but any time the mouse goes to the icon sidebar, for example, nothing happens.

I've been googling and messing with all the config options for several hours with no luck so far.

Any suggestions?